# Weekly count for 2 different date columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of tickets that have submit date and complete date.

Something like this:

```
Ticket   |  Submit_Date  |  Complete_Date
---------+---------------+-----------------
001      |   05/09/2020  |   05/09/2020
123      |   05/13/2020  |   05/16/2020
456      |   05/15/2020  |   05/22/2020
789      |   05/21/2020  |   05/23/2020
```

I need a count for how many were submitted each week and how many were completed each week.

The week number I can get with `DatePart(ww,'<some date here>')`.

I can pull up one or the other but cannot figure out how to do both.

For the table above I would like to get something like this:

```
week |         range         | Submitted | Worked | 
-----+-----------------------+-----------+--------+
19   | 05/03/2020-05/09/2020 |     1     |    1   |
20   | 05/10/2020-05/16/2020 |     2     |    1   |
21   | 05/17/2020-05/23/2020 |     1     |    2   |
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Pls share your SQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpivot using `apply` and then aggregate.  Getting the week is a little tricky:

```
select v2.week, sum(is_submit), sum(is_complete)
from t cross apply
     (values (submit_date, 1, 0), (complete_date, 0, 1)
     ) v(dte, is_submit, is_complete) cross apply
     (values (dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, v.dte), 0))) v2(week)
group by v2.week
order by v2.week;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6cfc4a95e4f2250d9f01288957cd8193) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for a different solution. Fiddle looks good. I will try it out as well

Comment: @whitedolphin . . . I think this is the better answer to your question.  It keeps all dates, even when weeks are missed in one of the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the 2 cases as 2 separate queries and join those 2.
Here is what I got - disregarding the range (which I left it to you as you didn't ask for it)

```
;With tCTE as
(select DATEPART(ww,Submit_Date) as wkNumSubmit, DATEPART(ww,Complete_Date) as wkNumComplete,   * from t) 

Select * from
(select wkNumSubmit, Count(distinct Submit_Date) as Submitted from tCTE Group By wkNumSubmit) s
inner join
(select wkNumComplete, Count(distinct Complete_Date) as Worked from tCTE Group By wkNumComplete) w
on s.wkNumSubmit = w.wkNumComplete
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2e97a7da1151934fcd09a657c33ac2bd)

To add all week numbers (consider all dates) here is what I suggest

```
;With tCTE   as
(select DATEPART(ww,Submit_Date) as wkNumSubmit, DATEPART(ww,Complete_Date) as wkNumComplete,   * from t),
 allDays (wkNum) as
(Select wkNumSubmit from tCTE Union Select wkNumComplete from tCTE )

Select * from allDays a
Left Join (select wkNumSubmit, Count(distinct Submit_Date) as Submitted from tCTE Group By wkNumSubmit) 
    as s on a.wkNum = s.wkNumSubmit
Left Join (select wkNumComplete, Count(distinct Complete_Date) as Worked from tCTE Group By wkNumComplete) 
    as w on a.wkNum = w.wkNumComplete
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6f6d04d431cfb1f1c351c99c73749307)

Comment: I should have thought of it myself, instead was trying to put it all into one select... range is not a problem, I got that working. Thank you!

Comment: @whitedolphin . . . You will lose any dates with this method that are not in both columns.

Comment: @whitedolphin, See my solution now.